# Доступ к бину в Java Spring

Tags: spring, java

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться или подскажите, где почитать...

В container из бина **Main** загружен component **ServiceA**. Но кроме как в конструкторе serviceA не "виден"... Для доступа приходится "просить" его через `container.getBean("serviceA")`.

Как обратиться к **ServiceA** через "." `(serviceA.hashCode());`?

Cейчас бросает NullPointerException...

```
    public class Main {

    private static BeanFactory beanFactory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");

    @Autowired
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    public void hello() {
        serviceA.hashCode();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.hello();
    }

}

@Service
public class ServiceA {

}
```

Comment: Побольше бы кода и понятного описания задачи.

Пока могу сказать, что прямой вызов `getBean()` - почти наверняка фэйл.

Comment: Добавил...

Comment: По-моему, проще связать B и С бины так же, как у вас связаны А и C.

Comment: отредактировал в соответствии с примером... 

В том-то и проблема, что связать В и С таким же образом не получается... 
@Autowired    private ServiceС serviceС  не возвращает serviceС   из контейнера, хотя он там есть... если просить через getBean - возвращает... именно в этом загвоздка...

Comment: <context:annotation-config/>

Такая строчка есть у вас в config.xml?

Comment: да, конечно... serviceA создается...

Comment: @Max Kudla, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Суть в том, что вы создаете объект Main через new. Это противоречит схеме Dependency Injection. В данном случае правильно объявить Main бином, получить main как бин. То есть:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = beanFactory.getBean(Main.class);
    main.hello();
}
```

вот так вот должно быть всё хорошо, если вы объявите Main как бин в xml файле.